# What is the best way to migrate data from oracle to dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

In order to migrate data form `oracle` to `Dynamics AX`, master data and *open* transnational data should be migrated to the system like `General ledger`, `vendors, customer`, `open payments`, `open invoice, PO`...

However, there are several methodology to use in order to migrate data to the target database.

For example :

- using `DMF`
- SQL server integration service.
- create AX job for each module and classes

What is the best methodology for the user to achieve this goal?

Please advise me, I am also looking for the most guaranteed one to avoid any failure since the finance.

Thanks.

Comment: I have not seen a single tool recommendation any where. This will help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/lifecycle-services/ax-2012/migrate-data-dixf

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548629.aspx#Select a tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way and the project will be of a much bigger scale than you think. A year ago we migrated from a heterogenous system based mostly on Oracle (but with different databases and systems) to AX 2012 R2. Just the migration project took more than a year of very iterative developmnent, in the end we were doing test migrations every 3 weeks for logistics data (coupled with live testing of the migrated data) and we did financial migrations abour every other month.

1. Generate export data from the original system in the desired structure. This includes all the transformations. We used a staging oracle database with views and / or staging tables. The SQL scripts and procedures used to generate the data are a project in itself, don't forget to use versioning. Partial data validation was part of these scripts as well (esp. important for financials, data in our original financial system differed a lot from how AX needs the data)
2. Create a tool that can semi-automatically export groups of data from the staging database to CSV files
3. Use a combination of jobs, DIXF and XLS imports. The XLS imports were used for ledgers (you can quite easily import a csv file into a journal and check everything before you post it). DIXF was used mainly for customers, vendors and adresses. The rest was done using jobs.